# canvas animate drawing lines

Tags: javascript, json, canvas

I have a JSON file with bunch of points that i wanted to slowly draw. I have read a [tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14484678/how-to-animate-the-drawing-of-a-curve-with-canvas) but this just draw one line. But what I want is to draw several lines by order (draw one first then other) and with different start points. Here is the JSON file:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "line": {
        "color": "#96c23b",
        "points": [
          {
            "x": 1,
            "y": 2
          },
          {
            "x": 2,
            "y": 3
          },
          {
            "x": 4,
            "y": 5
          },
          {
            "x": 7,
            "y": 8
          }
        ],
        "width": 2.0
      },
      "type": "line",
      "line_id": "1"
    },
    {
      "line": {
        "color": "#DF5453",
        "points": [
          {
            "x": 33,
            "y": 34
          },
          {
            "x": 34,
            "y": 35
          },
          {
            "x": 38,
            "y": 39
          },
          {
            "x": 40,
            "y": 42
          },
          {
            "x": 45,
            "y": 46
          }
        ],
        "width": 5.0
      },
      "type": "line",
      "line_id": "2"
    }
  ]
}
```

The speed of drawing does not matter.

I know how to parse the JSON and draw the lines in canvas without animation. Here is the code with jQuery:

```
var points_list =  {"data":[
  {"line":{"color":"#96c23b","points":[{"x":1,"y":2},{"x":2,"y":3},{"x":4,"y":5},{"x":7,"y":8}],"width":2.0},"type":"line","line_id":"1"},
  {"line":{"color":"#DF5453","points":[{"x":33,"y":34},{"x":34,"y":35},{"x":38,"y":39},{"x":40,"y":42},{"x":45,"y":46}],"width":5.0},"type":"line","line_id":"2"}
]}

function drawLines() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
    context = canvas.getContext("2d");

    $.each(points_list.data, function (key, value) {
        var info = value.line;
        var color = info.color;
        var width = info.width;
        var points = info.points;

        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(points[0].x, points[0].y);
        context.lineWidth = width;
        context.strokeStyle = color;
        context.fillStyle = color;

        for (var p = 1; p < points.length; p++) {
            context.lineTo(points[p].x, points[p].y);
        }
        context.stroke();
    });
}
```

Comment: Step 1: Can you draw the lines without any animation? That is, do you know how to parse the JSON to get an object you can work with in JavaScript, and can you write some code that uses the data in the array to draw the lines at all?

Comment: Sorry that I did not make it clear. I know how to parse the JSON and draw the lines in canvas without animation. Here is the code with jQuery:

Comment: The code didn't appear in your comment, but in any case please [edit] your question to show the relevant code directly in the question body. I assume you currently have some kind of loop to iterate over the array, in which case the simplest change would be to adapt that to a `setTimeout()`-based pseudo-loop.

Comment: Do you mean you want to show one fully drawn path, then an other one or to start each path form point[0] and at next frame add point[1] etc. ? Also, when you say that "*The speed of drawing does not matter*" in fact for us it may matter. Usually, for animations, we use `requestAnimationFrame` timing method, more reliable than any other timing method, but this will make a new call at the next screen refresh (~60 fps on most monitors). Anyway, you'll have to split at least one of your loops otherwise executed in the same frame, and wait until the next frame to increment its iterator

Comment: Yes, I want show the fully drawn path. I think the process will be like this: draw the first line(line_id is 1), start with the (point[0].x,point[0].y), then (point[1].x,point[1].y), and so on. After the first line drawn, draw the second line(line_id is 2), from the point[0] to point[1] ... Sorry to say that speed doesn't matter, actually I know I need to use the `requestAnimationFrame` to animate the drawing process, but I use the code from the tutorial I mentioned before, then I draw two lines at the same time, which is not I want to do.

Comment: Well you just have to take the code in the other Q/A, when the first path is fully drawn, increment your outer iterator (the one used for `points_list.data`) and call the path drawing again. Do this until all pathes are drawn and you're good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of tracking the positions of the outerList and the innerList using variables. The outerlist (points_list.data) is tracked using lineIndexB the innerList (points_list.data.line.points) is tracked using lineIndexA.

Each time the function drawLines fires, the next line segment is drawn, then the lineIndexA variable is incremented. If the line segment is complete, then lineIndexB is incremented.

This is using the setTimeout function to make the animation work, it could easily be converted to requestAnimationFrame.

```js
var points_list =  {"data":[
  {"line":{"color":"#96c23b","points":[{"x":1,"y":2},{"x":2,"y":3},{"x":4,"y":5},{"x":7,"y":8}],"width":2.0},"type":"line","line_id":"1"},
  {"line":{"color":"#DF5453","points":[{"x":33,"y":34},{"x":34,"y":35},{"x":38,"y":39},{"x":40,"y":42},{"x":45,"y":46}],"width":5.0},"type":"line","line_id":"2"}
]};

var lineIndexA = 1;
var lineIndexB = 0;

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
canvas.width = 500;
canvas.height = 500;
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

function drawLines() {
   
 var value = points_list.data[lineIndexB];
  var info = value.line;
  var color = info.color;
  var width = info.width;
  var points = info.points;

  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(points[lineIndexA-1].x, points[lineIndexA-1].y);
  context.lineWidth = width;
  context.strokeStyle = color;
  context.fillStyle = color;
  context.lineTo(points[lineIndexA].x, points[lineIndexA].y);        
  context.stroke();
    
  lineIndexA = lineIndexA + 1;
  if (lineIndexA>points.length-1) {
   lineIndexA = 1;
    lineIndexB = lineIndexB + 1;
  }
        
  //stop the animation if the last line is exhausted...
  if (lineIndexB>points_list.data.length-1) return;
    
  setTimeout(function() {
               drawLines()
                    }, 1000);
}

drawLines();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks, this really helped. Now I'm trying to control the speed by using requestAnimationFrame.